# Azure automl get underlying code for training model

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-auto-ml

I've been testing a model using azureml for image classification. I see in this guide that it should be possible to view the underlying code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-generate-automl-training-code?view=azureml-api-1&viewFallbackFrom=azureml-api-2

It's creating a seresnext model but when I go to the model and view generated code I just see some automl configs in script.py (automl_settings, mltable_data_json). I'd like to view the actual model code so I can adjust it in my own azureml compute session. Something like the generate_algorithm_config in the above tutorial. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the training code in the Azure Machine Learning studio UI on the Outputs + logs tab of the selected model. The file `script.py` contains the model's training code that you may want to analyze with the featurization steps, specific algorithm used, and hyperparameters.

[image]

“AutoML CodeGen” Preview documentation and feedback/issues channel:
GitHub repo: [Azure/automl-codegen-preview: AutoML code generation (github.com)](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAzure%2Fautoml-codegen-preview&data=04%7C01%7CBartosz.Czernicki%40microsoft.com%7C1eaee16ffc8e4d7e947108d968b22caa%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637655936738835883%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=bnN0TekyO0TyQKmwtW4NlUasmZbSyLsXsfonK6HR%2F%2FU%3D&reserved=0)